# Validating strings with Java and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

`vo.getResultFun()` and `cod` returns `'G'`

**Java validation**

```
if ( genericValidator.isBlankOrNull(vo.getResultFun()) || 
          !("G".equalsIgnoreCase(vo.getResultFun()) || "B".equalsIgnoreCase(vo.getResultFun()))) {
            throw new UCNaoCadastradaGerBenException();
        }
```

**NodeJS**

```
if (Validator.isNullUndefinedEmpty(cod) ||
            !(Validator.isEqual(cod, 'B', true) || Validator.isEqual(cod, 'G', true))) {
            callback(Translate.__('K1.CH1', lang), null);
```

**isEqual**

```
  static isEqual(str1: string, str2: string, ignoreCase: boolean = false): boolean {
    let ret = false;
    if (ignoreCase) {
      ret =
        (str1 === undefined && str2 === undefined) ||
        (str1 === null && str2 === null) ||
        (str1 != null && str2 != null && typeof str1 === 'string' && typeof str2 === 'string' && str1.toUpperCase() === str2.toUpperCase());
    } else {
      ret =
        (str1 === undefined && str2 === undefined) ||
        (str1 === null && str2 === null) ||
        (str1 != null && str2 != null && typeof str1 === 'string' && typeof str2 === 'string' && str1 === str2);
    }
    return ret;
  }
```

Why NodeJS return the callback and Java don't throws the exception?

Comment: Since the problem is actually with the JavaScript part, I added the JavaScript tag. But those parameters' declarations look weird. Is this actually TypeScript?

Comment: Yep, it's typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of this js part :

```
!(Validator.isEqual(cod, 'B', true) || Validator.isEqual(cod, 'G', true))
```

is `false` as the result of this java part:

```
!("G".equalsIgnoreCase(vo.getResultFun()) || "B".equalsIgnoreCase(vo.getResultFun()))
```

So there are several options :

- `Validator.isNullUndefinedEmpty` doesn't works
- `cod` is not strictly equals to 'G'
- The callback function is not called

Comment: Changing Validator.isNullUndefinedEmpty to Validator.isNullUndefined resolved. Thanks!